# AMD gaming motherboard upgrade

Tags: gaming, motherboard, video-editing

I'm looking for a motherboard to replace my old one that's been giving me problems lately (See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1027376/custom-built-computer-wont-turn-on-anymore)).

The PC is used for heavy gaming (All new games running max settings; GTA V, Fallout 4, etc). It's used for a fair amount of video/photo editing as well.

**Requirements:**

- AM3+ CPU socket
- Budget is around $150USD
- USB 3.0 header support
- At least 4 USB ports on the back (USB2.0 is fine)
- Built in 5.1 surround sound support (No additional sound card needed)
- WiFi, bluetooth, integrated video and PS/2 are *not* required.
- Needs to work with the rest of my components, obviously (See below)

HDD - [Seagate Barracuda 2 TB HDD SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA8UW3GP4298)

CPU Cooler - [Cooler Master V8 GTS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835103189)

PCU - [SeaSonic X Series X-850 (SS-850KM3 Active PFC F3) 850W ATX12V](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151102)

SSD - [Crucial MX100 2.5" 256GB SATA III MLC Internal](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6232GM5508)

RAM - [G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB (4 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 2133](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231473)

CPU - [AMD FX-9590 Vishera 8-Core 4.7 GHz Socket AM3+ 220W - Black Edition](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7BB3T72010)

GPU - [EVGA GeForce GTX 980 4GB SC GAMING ACX 2.0](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814487079)

Tower - [Thermaltake Level 10 GT Snow Edition](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811133192)

**Update:**

I raised my budget to 150usd,  that would probably be a more logical budget for a decent board. I'm also flexible on the price,  if it's more expensive than my budget,  but is an overall better choice,  then go ahead and suggest it. As long as it's not way out of the budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing my answer your CPU is compatible only with 990FX motherboards. So I deleted second option because it wasn't compatible with your CPU. I also added cheaper alternative which will work in your setup.

---

**MSI 990FXA GAMING - [149.99 on newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130859)**

This motherboard meets all your requirements and is good for OC. Additionally it has really good software. It's really solid construction.

**ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0 - [134.99 on newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1N83UD9887)**

This is cheaper alternative which is also good constuction and meets your requirements.

Comment: Both good choices but damn is the MSI marketing poster full of a bunch of nonsense.